# Как поправить код, чтоб верстка не съезжала?

Tags: html, css, php

У меня имеется вот такой код с закрытием input'а, он не правильно отображается в браузерах, а если я поставлю правильное закрытие сразу после указанной длины поля />, то у меня echo не правильно работает и отображается отдельным сообщением, которая выводится за пределы этого input'а.

```
  <?php
 if (!isset($myrow['avatar']) or $myrow['avatar']=='') {
 print <<<HERE
 <div class ="form_auth">
 <form action="testreg.php" method="post">
 <div class="field_auth">
 <div class = "login"><div class="color_login"><label>Ваш логин:</label><br/>
 <input name="login" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20"
 HERE;
if (isset($_COOKIE['login']))
{
echo ' value="'.$_COOKIE["login"].'">';
}
?>
```

Comment: забудьте про этот быдлоспособ вывода контента с помощью HEREDOC

Comment: mountpoint,а как надо?

Comment: Потому что используя закрытие, вы закрываете тег, и все далее лежащее находится уже вне него. Ваш капитан.

Очевидно, вы хотели добиться вот этого:

    <input name="login" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" <?php echo isset($_COOKIE['login'])?'value="'.$_COOKIE['login'].'"':''; ?>/>

Comment: @Fike, я понимаю что при закрытие он находится вне. Попробовал сделать по вашему, так он вообще перестал отображаться на странице. Если бы все было так просто((

Comment: @lifting, потому что пустое поле выглядит как белый прямоугольник, возможно, без обрамления.

Comment: @lifting, все, разглядел heredoc. Смысл в том, что он не нужен и html должен лежать вне тегов php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вставлять переменные прямо в HEREDOC, который ведет себя как строка в двойных кавычках. Правда я бы все равно отказался от его использования несмотря на то, что он дает прирост в производительности по сравнению с <?...?> HTML <?...?>

```
print <<<HERE
 <div class ="form_auth">
 <form action="testreg.php" method="post">
 <div class="field_auth">
 <div class = "login"><div class="color_login"><label>Ваш логин:</label><br/>
 <input name="login" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" value="$_COOKIE[login]" />
HERE;
```

Если требуется еще проверить что-либо, то лучше это сделать до HEREDOC, возможно сохранив в переменную, и потом уже вставить.

Answer (score 1):

Я может быть чего-то не понимаю, но почему бы просто не сделать вот так:

```
<input name="login" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" value="<?php echo $_COOKIE['login']; ?>">
```

Comment: я так уже пробовал, после чего у меня вообще ничего не отображается на странице.

Comment: Возможно у вас где-то синтаксическая ошибка, что-то забыли закрыть.

Comment: Нет, только что проверял, все закрыто, синтаксических ошибок не нашел.

Comment: Дебажте. Выводите что-либо на страницу с начала и смотрите где перестает выводить.

Answer (score 0):

Пора уже учиться вводить html  более красиво.

```
<?php 
  doSomething(); 
?> 
<div class ="form_auth">
 <form action="testreg.php" method="post">
 <div class="field_auth">
 <div class = "login"><div class="color_login"><label>Ваш логин:</label><br/>
 <input name="login" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" value=<? echo $_COOKIE['login'] ; ?> >

<?

?>
```

Comment: Попробовал, так после чего не отображается страница =(

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
 if (!isset($myrow['avatar']) or $myrow['avatar']=='')
    {
  ?>
 <div class ="form_auth">
 <form action="testreg.php" method="post">
 <div class="field_auth">
 <div class = "login"><div class="color_login"><label>Ваш логин:</label><br/>
 <input name="login" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20"

<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['login']))
   {
     echo " value= ' ".$_COOKIE["login"]." ' >";
   }

   }
?>
```

Забудьте про print <<<HERE